# show message after form submit laravel

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

hi I'm a beginner in Laravel I want to use [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) in my Laravel website but it did not display in the view

I use  branch dist from Github

so in my `**master_layout.blade.php**` this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charest="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    **<link href="css/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">**
    <link href="css/main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favorite-icon.png" />
</head>
<body>
    @include('include/Navbar')
    <main>

        @include('include/Sidebar')

        @include('include/HamburgerSidebar')

        <div class="container">
            @yield('Content')
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="Js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    **<script src="Js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>**
    <script src="Js/main-JQ.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my controller store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request_order=$request->section_order;
        if(empty($request_order)){
            $order_last = Section::latest('section_order')->get();
            if(empty($order_last)){
                $request_order=1;
            }else{
                $request_order=$order_last[0]['section_order']+1;
            }
        }

        $request->validate([
            'section_name' => ['required','min:3'],
            'section_pic' =>['image']
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('section_pic');

        if ( $image === null) {
            $image_name = 'default_img.jpg';
        }else{
            $image_name = rand(1, 20) . time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path('img'),$image_name);
        }

        $input_data = array(
        'section_order' => $request_order,
        'section_name' => $request->section_name,
        'section_pic' => $image_name
        );

        Section::create($input_data);

            return redirect('/Sections')->withSuccess('Success message');
    }
```

and in my view:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
<script type="text/javascript">
   Swal.fire(
           'Good job!',
           'Successfully Saved!',
           'success'
   );
</script>
@endif
```

the store function works fine but not display sweetalert in my view

and I put all CSS and js file and images folder in public folder is that correct or not?

Comment: There is ton of tutorials on how to use SweetAlert with Laravel: 
https://medium.com/@hossain.naime/how-to-implement-sweet-alert-in-laravel-application-7cfe0fe4dd57

There is one, maybe it can help you.

Comment: @ N. Djokic .... yes, but what i did wrong in my code

Comment: is there any error in your `console` when you submit the form ?

Comment: try to add your `Swal` object in `window.onload` event to make sure that your page is loaded

Comment: @ Joseph .....yes ... this is the error ( Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
    at Sections:1224)

Comment: thanks alto @ Joseph  it's work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @ Joseph his comment solve my problem 
i use window.onload and it work fine

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function massge() {
  Swal.fire(
            'Good job!',
            'Successfully Saved!',
            'success'
        );
  }

  window.onload = massge;
 </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller :

```
  session()->flash("success","Success Message");
  return redirect('/Sections');
```

## Blade File

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            swal("Deleted!", "Data has been Deleted.", "success"),
                swal({
                    title: {{ session()->get('success') }},
                    text: "Your Custom or Dynamic SUccess message put here",
                    type: "success"})

        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: what if i want to show error massage from validation

Comment: would you like to show error in list way or individual error message under field ? @George

Comment: @if($errors->has('inputName'))    <strong> {{ $errors->first("inputName") }} </strong>         @endif